# You don’t sound like... vs You don’t sound

Tags: adjective-phrases

Could you say which sentence is more used if both are correct?

> You don’t sound American.

vs

> You don’t sound like American.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is idiomatic. "American" is being used as a pure adjective.

> You don't sound healthy
>
> You don't sound happy
>
> You don't sound very loud

These are are all descriptions of the sound that you make.

The second is not idiomatic. "Like" expects a noun (or pronoun) to follow with the appropriate article. But "American" is an adjective. What is happening is that what is meant is "American person." A word that is understood is dropped. But, strangely, the article is not dropped. (Do not ask me to explain why. Like the heart, the tongue has reasons that reason would never say.) So what is idiomatic is

> You don't sound like an American.